# How to send Hyperlink(Task URL) in CSV Export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hyperlink

I want show Task_Url in the CSV file, I have used this query for CSV -

```
user_trackers = TaskTimeTracker.joins(:task).where("(task_time_trackers.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)",Date.current.beginning_of_month, Date.current.end_of_month )
```

@trackers = user_trackers

This is the CSV method I have used -

```
def export_csv
      columns = %w(Date Task Task_URL TimeSpent Log)
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << columns
        @trackers.each do |t|
          csv << [t.created_at,
                    t.task.name,

                    t.time_spent,
                    t.description ]
        end
      end
    end
```

This is the Task Model I have used.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
      TASK_TYPES = { bug: 'Bug', enhancement: 'Enhancement', feature: 'Feature'}
      belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :task_time_trackers, dependent: :nullify
      validates :task_type,presence: true
end
```

Task_Time_Tracker Model

```
class TaskTimeTracker < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :user
    validates :description,presence:true
    validates :time_spent,presence:true
end
```

Schema Info of Task_Time_Tracker

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: task_time_trackers
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  description :text(65535)
#  time_spent  :float(24)
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  task_id     :integer
#  user_id     :integer
```

Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is implemented in a controller or model?

Test this:

```
def export_csv
  columns = %w(Date Task Task_URL TimeSpent Log)
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << columns
    @trackers.each do |t|
      csv << [t.created_at,
                t.task.name,
                task_url(t.task),
                t.time_spent,
                t.description ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `task_url' for

Comment: This method is implemented in a controller or model?

Comment: I have made a separate class for it under module Export

Comment: Add this `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` In export and test again `tasks_url(t.task)`